# UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to write to text file in C#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm trying to write a blank text file which is included within my installer but i'm getting the following error;

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Hex Technologies\wamplocation.txt' is denied.
```

It seems to be the permissions of the file once it's installed through my installer, but how can I set the file to be fully modifiable once the file installed?! Can this be done through C#?!

EDITTED;

```
           wamp_url = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
           String EnviromentPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
           StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(EnviromentPath + @"\Hex Technologies\wamplocation.txt");
           outfile.Write(wamp_url);
           outfile.Close();
```

Comment: Window's 7 ?, if so you should be writing to ProgramData not Program Files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not store your modifyable data files in the Program Files path.  Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`

The Program Files\... path is protected against modification by normal users on Win7+.  It would be a bad idea to try to circumvent that protection.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting another error, see my comment below, could you help?

Answer (score 2):

The likleyhood is the UAC is getting in your way.

Ideally your program shouldn't be writing to this location, it this modification file is to be modified during an install process and nowhere else you need to make sure that you are running elevated.

If this file is to be modified at run time you should consider the use of either %appdata% for user data or %programdata% for program data instead of program files.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm receiving a message saying the 'the file is being used by another process'. I've inserted my code above to show what my code looks like!

Comment: does the folder "Hex Technologies" exist in Application data?

Comment: Yes, I double checked the string which I fed into the streamwriter and it match the url for the .txt file.

Comment: download [handle](http://live.sysinternals.com/handle.exe), run it to find which process has your file locked

Comment: I run http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 and nothing appeared for the txt file?!